# Run Node js application on web server gives error This site can’t be reached <IP_ADDRESS> took too long to respond

Tags: node.js, port

I am new to Node.js. Please, help me for the below issue.

I want to run node.js application on host server (centOs 6) [NOT ON LOCALHOST].

> node -v

v8.12.0

> npm -v

6.4.1

code for hello.js:-

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

> node hello.js

Now, when i run above command in terminal, it shows the text which is written in console.log as below:

Server running at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/

But, when i open that url into browser it show below:

> This site can’t be reached
>  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx took too long to
>   respond.
>  Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>  Checking the proxy and the firewall
>   Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>  ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Note: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the server ip address.

Should i need to ask host provider to enable the port?

On the same ip address 5 website is working as it shows in whm.

Your help will be really grateful!!!

Thanks

Comment: port 3000 has been blocked for public viewing may be .Which server running on port 80? is it apache

Comment: Thanks for comment.
How to check it on port 80 which server is running?